# I cannot configure PDF using Page Print

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a report using html and CSS.
I'm not able to make the PDF view equal to the html in an expressed way.

My page looked like this:

![enter image description here][1]

In PDF it didn't look like HTML:

[image]

I tried:

```
<style>
      page {
        background: white;
        display: block;
        margin: 0 auto;
        margin-bottom: 0.5cm;
        box-shadow: 0 0 0.5cm rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    }

        page[size="A4"] {
            width: 12cm;
            height: 100%;
        }

            page[size="A4"][layout="landscape"] {
                width: 29.7cm;
                /*height: 21cm;*/
            }

   
</style>
```

---

HTML:

```
<page size="A4">
    <div class="container body-content">
       <table class="table table-bordered table-condensed" style="margin-top: -22px">
           <tbody>
                <tr style="">
                   <td style="border: 1px solid #ffffff !important; padding-top: 13px;">
                        <div class="row">
                             <div class="col col-xs-6" style="margin-top: 14px;margin-bottom:1%; padding-right: 0px;">
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                   <img class="pull-right border-solid-1 img-prod" src="@itens.xFileImagePrincipal" alt="">
                               </div>
                               </div>
                               <div class="col col-xs-5 col-md-2" style="padding-left: 0px; ">
                                   <div class="col-md-12 border-solid-1" style="padding-left: 20px; min-height: 200px !important; margin-top: 14px !important;">
                                                            @*TODO: Modelo*@
                                                            <div class="row p-t-10">
                                                                <h6><strong>Cód.:</strong> <strong style="font-size: 17px !important;">@itens.xCodAlternativo</strong></h6>
                                                            </div>

                                                            <div class="row margem p-r-10">
                                                                <h6><strong>Descrição: &nbsp;@itens.xDetalhes</strong></h6>
                                                            </div>

                                                            <div class="row produto p-t-5">

                                                            {
                                                                <div class="row" style="padding-top: 10px;">
                                                                    <strong class="color-red">Preço:&nbsp; R$ @itens.vlrTabela1Formatado / @itens.xUnidadeMedida</strong>
                                                                </div>
                                                            }

                                                            @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(itens.xTabela2))
                                                            {
                                                                <div class="row" style="padding-top: 10px;">
                                                                    <strong class="color-red">Preço:&nbsp; R$ @itens.vlrTabela2Formatado / @itens.xUnidadeMedida</strong>
                                                                </div>
                                                            }

                                                            @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(itens.xTabela3))
                                                            {
                                                                <div class="row" style="padding-top: 10px;">
                                                                    <strong class="color-red">Preço:&nbsp; R$ @itens.vlrTabela3Formatado / @itens.xUnidadeMedida</strong>
                                                                </div>
                                                            }

                                                            @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(itens.xTabela4))
                                                            {
                                                                <div class="row" style="padding-top: 10px;">
                                                                    <strong class="color-red">Preço:&nbsp; R$ @itens.vlrTabela4Formatado / @itens.xUnidadeMedida</strong>
                                                                </div>
                                                            }
                                                            @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(itens.xTabela5))
                                                            {
                                                                <div class="row" style="padding-top: 10px;">
                                                                    <strong class="color-red">Preço:&nbsp; R$ @itens.vlrTabela5Formatado / @itens.xUnidadeMedida</strong>
                                                                </div>
                                                            }
                                                            @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(itens.xTabela6))
                                                            {
                                                                <div class="row" style="padding-top: 10px;">
                                                                    <strong class="color-red">Preço:&nbsp; R$ @itens.vlrTabela6Formatado / @itens.xUnidadeMedida</strong>
                                                                </div>
                                                            }
                                                            @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(itens.xTabela7))
                                                            {
                                                                <div class="row" style="padding-top: 10px;">
                                                                    <strong class="color-red">Preço:&nbsp; R$ @itens.vlrTabela7Formatado / @itens.xUnidadeMedida</strong>
                                                                </div>
                                                            }
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
</div>
```

I've tried everything and researched a lot about it, but I didn't get any results. Final result:
[image]

Comment: when you're using such a methode it's not always from your codes, check the settings of your browser, if you're using chrome try it with firefox

Comment: What's the style of `.container` and `body-content`?

Comment: .body-content {
        padding-left: 5px !important;
        padding-right: 5px !important;
    }

The .container is getting normal from the bootstrap. mine .body-content is above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An A4 page is **21cm (210mm)** wide, which is hard-coded to be that wide in portrait.
The page should not be assigned as size *A4* when you don't need it:

```css
page {
  width: 12cm;
  // ...
}
```

So, removing `[size="A4"]`.

Reference: [CSS page size at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%40page/size)

Comment: I used it according to your opinion but it stayed the same way.

 page[size="A4"] {
            width: 120mm;
            /*height: 100%;*/
        }

Comment: Again, it is `210mm`, *not* `120mm`. Write `21cm` or `210mm`.

Comment: Please clarify these specifications in your original post. Your first screenshots shows the page full-width and you wrote the PDF doesn't look like the HTML, which only has its width incorrect as far as I could tell. So please clarify what it should look like.

Comment: Final result in the description:

Comment: Final result in the description ok?

If you know of any format that can be the same.

Comment: Now the first image is not displayed anymore. Please tell us with words what you expect and what is not working. It is still not clear to me. See [How to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Maybe you should just remove the [size="A4"] since you don't want A4?

Comment: It worked out.
Thank you my friend.

Comment: Okay very good, I'll also update the answer accordingly.